# How do I reference a cell in an Excel data table without using the cell coordinates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I do a summation on the values of a set of cells in an Excel data table. The problem is when I sort the table, the values in those cells change (because the records get sorted) and this changes the value of my summation. I would like to reference those cells in another manner rather than specifying them by their coordinates (e.g. A1, B3, C4, etc). Is this possible in Excel?

If not, is there a way to get the effect I want?

Edit:

[image: My Worksheet]

Towards the bottom, the cell labeled `Original Investment` takes a sum as shown in the formula bar. When I sort by `Date of Purchase`, the `Original Investment` summation sums the wrong data.

Comment: What's the table look like? Use a vlookup?

Comment: Agreed; it would really help to see what you're data looks like, and exactly what result you're expecting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another column called `Dividend` and for each record, marked that field as 'Yes' or 'No'. Then, in my summation cell, I used this formula: `=SUMIF(mytable[Dividend],"No",mytable[Original Value])` where `mytable` is the name given to this data table.